# Control does not contain a definition for "xxx" when in an array of controls

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, controls

I have an array of controls that I have created:

```
public static string[] ldcNames = new string[16] {"ledIndicator0", "ledIndicator1", "ledIndicator2", "ledIndicator3", "ledIndicator4", "ledIndicator5", "ledIndicator6", "ledIndicator7", "ledIndicator8", "ledIndicator9", "ledIndicator10", "ledIndicator11", "ledIndicator12", "ledIndicator13", "ledIndicator14", "ledIndicator15"};
```

In other arrays of General Winform controls that I have made, I can access the properties of the controls. The above Array is an array of LedIndicators from `TA.Winforms.Controls` package.

I access the other controls in this manner:

```
var lbl1 = this.Controls[Global.lblNames[rangeLabel]];` and `lbl1.Text = "xxxxx"
```

This works perfectly.  Attempting to do the same for the LedIndicator control results in the following error: (Where "Cadence" is underlined with a red squiggly line in the VS IDE

```
var ld1 = this.Controls[Global.ldcNames[rowNum]];
ld1.Cadence = CadencePattern.SteadyOn;
```

> Error CS1061  'Control' does not contain a definition for 'Cadence' and
> no accessible extension method 'Cadence' accepting a first argument of
> type 'Control' could be found.

I am able to access the standard properties but not any of the, I don't know, extended or unique properties of this control.

Completely lost here and desperately need help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check what Type is `ld1` in `var ld1 = this.Controls[Global.ldcNames[rowNum]];`? It's of course of Type `Control`. You have to cast it to the Type that exposes the `Cadence`  property

Comment: *"I have an array of controls"*. That's a `string` array, not a `Control` array.

Comment: *"This works perfectly"*. That's because `Text` is a member of the `Control` class - all controls have a `Text` property. You can only access members of the `Control` class via a reference of type `Control`. If you want to access a member of a more derived type then you have to cast as that type.

Comment: I appreciate all of your help, but I had no idea how to cast to a type.  Idle_Mind answered what needed to be done and also showed me what needed to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have stated, you need to CAST the control to the correct type, `LedIndicator` in your case:

```
LedIndicator ld1 = (LedIndicator)this.Controls[Global.ldcNames[rowNum]];
ld1.Cadence = CadencePattern.SteadyOn;
```

You can also use the `as` keyword:

```
LedIndicator ld1 = this.Controls[Global.ldcNames[rowNum]] as LedIndicator;
ld1.Cadence = CadencePattern.SteadyOn;
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  Tested and working perfectly.  I'd never run into this before and had no idea how to do anything like this, and I appreciate your direct answer and also instructions on how to implement the answer.  Many thanks.